# Wordpress get userid from query param and redirect with username

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm new to WordPress and I have a question in `add_rewrite_rule` function.
I want to redirect

```
/players?&mode=profile&uid=1
```

to somethiing like this:

```
/members/{playername}
```

In order to do this, I have to rewrite `/players` to `/members` and catch `mode` and `uid` query param and get playername from `uid` and redirect to `/members/{playername}`.
Any advice?